# Is it possible to add Facebook SDK to my iOS Widget Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, ios-extensions

Following the [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/) provided by Facebook
I'm trying to add Facebook SDK to use analytics for my widget extension

Seems not easy because the SDK asks to use `CFBundleURLSchemes` and `AppDelegate.swift` that are not present in the widget extension using SwiftUI.

Does anybody had the same problem or is there a workaround to use analysis on the iOS extensions?

Thanks in advance.